# How to install Babel in Windows OS?

Tags: windows-7, ecmascript-6, babeljs

How can I install the Babel js in my computer? I've watched many tutorials about installing Babel but all of them are using Mac OS, and they just use the Terminal. I've tried to do the same with Command Prompt but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have nodejs installed?

Comment: Not yet, but I have an installer. What will be the next step after I installed it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

start by installing Nodejs https://nodejs.org/en/

Using Babel depends on what you're trying to do. I assume you want to build a basic html / css / js page to try it out.

If you're familiar with github, clone this project:
https://github.com/rauschma/webpack-babel-demo

If you're not familiar with github, theres a link to download the zip file, extract and type `npm install` from the command prompt in the directory which will download all the necessary files needed to load and package Babel.

After that finishes type `npm start` which tells Babel to compile (via Webpack) after any changes to your javascript files and launches a server at http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Does the `npm install` only work if node.js is installed?

Comment: Thanks, man. I've always thought `npm` only works in MAC OS. I'm wrong